# Node D3 geojson Pathing Issue

Tags: node.js, d3.js, geojson, path-finding

So I'm trying to put a us.geojson file into a function to manipulate the data to appear as a map. Pretty standard D3 stuff I think. Anyway, I've placed the us.geojson file next to the other file that is referencing it. But I get a 404. I've checked the name of the files until my eyes bled. What's wrong here?

Here is my map.js file that is loading the us.geojson on line 7:

```
$(function() {

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 760)
        .attr("height", 700)

    d3.json("us.geojson", function (data) {
        var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var areas = group.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue ")
    }); 
});
```

And here is my file structure: [File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzjx0.png)

Comment: put the us.geojson directly inside the public folder

Comment: nice, that worked. but why? Does node only allow js files into javascripts?

Comment: d3.json is an ajax call and it will load from root ...its not relative